# TextView not showing entirely

Tags: android, android-layout

If my text in the TextView **tweet** is too long then the end of the text is going out of the screen.

I try to apply some answer I found for this problem but it's not working.

Here is my layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/item_border_shadow">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tweet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/action_share_plusone"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/button_plusone"
            android:layout_weight="1" />  

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/action_facebook"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/button_facebook"
            android:layout_weight="1" />  

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/action_twitter"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/button_twitter"
            android:layout_weight="1" />  

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/action_share"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/button_social_share"
            android:layout_weight="1" />  

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I fix this problem to display the textview entirely ?

Edit 1 : I want the text displayed entirely without any action (no scroll, no marquee)

Comment: You can use marquee for this. So it will move horizontally.

Comment: I don't want to use marquee. I want to display the text entirely without animation.

Comment: Then try for scrollview

Comment: I don't want the user need to scroll. I want the text displayed entirely without any action.

Comment: Make single line false. You have set android:layout_height="0dp". What does it mean? &

Comment: If I set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` Eclipse say `Use a layout_height of 0dp instead of wrap_content for better 
 performance`. And even with `android:singleLine="false"` it doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57490/discussion-between-rit-and-guillaume).

Comment: Have u think it is possible to show content of textview without any scroll or marquee even content is larger than screen ?

Answer (score 0):

add this in your TextView tweet

```
  android:singleLine="false"
  android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

Comment: The problem is still there.

Comment: Change layout_height to "match_parent" in the top LinearLayout  @guillaume

Comment: I'm still having the problem